# Heinlein book(s) with FTL travel?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, ftl-drive

I'm a new Heinlein fan and also an FTL (faster-than-light) fan.  Did he write any books where FTL was possible?  All the ones I've read so far have been intra-system (Sol) only.

Comment: This is not an off-topic list question, because it is limited to the finite universe of Heinlein novels.

Comment: According the the answer (accepted and upvoted 17-0) to the meta question {Are *all* list questions off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/are-all-list-questions-off-topic), " finite and well-scoped list questions are allowed here." I suppose that's why all those questions asking "How many alien women has Kirk slept with" or "How many people has this superhero killed" were not closed as off-topic.

Comment: Heinlein wrote about 35 novels, a finite number.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- **Methusaleh's Children** featured an experimental FTL drive by one of the characters that was essential to the plot; in **Time Enough for Love**, its sequel the same FTL drive is discovered to also work as a time-travel drive.
- **The Number of the Beast**, **The Cat Who Walks Through Walls**, and **To Sail Beyond the Sunset** all have a universe-hopping device that serves as an FTL stand-in
- **Starship Troopers** involves FTL, as Michael indicated, the book doesn't really get into details.
- **Tunnel in the Sky** and, I think, **Have Spacesuit - Will Travel** and **Starman Jones** all involve FTL or similar systems, at least peripherally.

Comment: Forgot Starman Jones (only read it once). Have Spacesuit-Will Travel is my all-time favorite though! *hand-slap*

Comment: _Have Spacesuit - Will Travel_ most definitely does have an FTL drive (although not until the latter part of the book).

Answer (score 13):

From the [Faster Than Light and Normal Space Starship and Spaceship Drive List](http://www.artsbooks.info/space-travel-list-ftl-sublight-gateways-version-1-1/) ...

- **Number of the Beast**.  Based in a 6-dimensional space, you can instantaneously travel to where you want to go provided you know the proper vectors.
- **Starman Jones**. The starship in question accelerated to the speed of light where it
  jumped elsewhere.
- **The Cat Who Walks Through Walls**, **To Sail Beyond The Sunset**. Drive is size of a sewing machine case and can instantaneously place the vessel anywhere, anywhen, in any universe with a velocity up to the speed of light.  Computer controlled and uses virtually no power.
- **Future History**. In one of the Lazarus Long stories an inertialess drive is used to go FTL.

Possibly *Starship Troopers* and *Citizen of the Galaxy*...but I don't remember the references.

Comment: Ah, your answer didn't show up until I posted mine! I think you're right about Citizen of the Galaxy, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @neilfein My 20+ year old copy of Citizen is around here somewhere.....I'll dig out a ref if I find the bloody book.

Comment: Definitely right about Citizen.

Comment: technically Number doesn't use FTL travel as no actual speed is involved :)

Answer (score 13):

In addition to those already mentioned:

- *Friday*
- *Citizen of the Galaxy*
- *The Star Beast*

Answer (score 8):

I believe *Starship Troopers* had FTL, but I am unclear as to how it works. The book dealt more with planetary assaults than with space travel. They were definately on other planets, though. Another book of his had "gates" to other planets, through which colonization expeditions proceeded. <strike>I do not recall the title - please edit or leave a comment if you know it.</strike> It was *Tunnel in the sky*.

Comment: 'Tunnel in the Sky' was a good one.  I've read this one and didn't even think of gate travel as FTL.  Technically it is, but I've got FTL=spaceship stuck in my head.  :)

Answer (score 7):

I think **Time for the Stars** is the only one no-one else has mentioned.   After they've spent most of the book travelling relativistically, an FTL drive is introduced at the end of the book.

Comment: Variable Star by Spider Robinson, based on an outline by RH, also has FTL pop up later in the book.

Comment: The book revolves around FTL communication on STL sharships.

Comment: @BenCrowell That's true, but at the end the communications leads to a breakthrough in FTL travel and they all get retrieved off the ships.